# login and register in nestjs with firebase

Tags: firebase, nestjs

I want to create Nestjs app which do login and register like frontend, before I write this code in my Nodejs app like this:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase);

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        .then((e) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .currentUser.getIdToken(true)
                .then((idToken) => {                    
                    res.json({idToken});
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });


});
```

now I want use it in Nestjs but I got some errors.

I tried this but not working:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
firebase.initializeApp(clientAccount);

auth.initializeAuth(firebase.getApp());
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('/register')
  registerUser(@Body() body) {
    const { email, password } = body;
    console.log({ email, password });
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth.getAuth(), email, password)
      .then(async (user) => {
        return user;
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        // res.status(500).send(err);
        throw new BadGatewayException(err);
      });
  }
```

**createUserWithEmailAndPassword** function  takes three arguments but I don't know what's the first argument?

I get this error : BadGatewayException: Firebase: Error (auth/configuration-not-found).

Comment: What Error you get?

Comment: this error: BadGatewayException: Firebase: Error (auth/configuration-not-found). @Youba

Comment: check the package name if is the same in config, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619945/error-auth-configuration-not-an-internal-error-has-occurred)

Comment: I know that I should have enabled authentication in firebase console, in authentication menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error when the authentication source you are trying to use has not been enabled in the firebase project. Go to the firebase console and enable authentication. For example:

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, but I wrote comment before in question comments